A short story set in near future about trying to get students into Shakespeare
I'm trying to remember a science fiction short story written somewhere between the 60s and 80s about a society who are trying to make shakespeare more entertaining with nudity and humour, watching it on screen. The students or society can't get into it but in the end a woman who read the original Shakespeare won people over and was showered with awards.

There already is a lot of humor (often coarse humor, but not including nudity) in Shakespeare. Playing to the groundlings and all that...

And Madly Teach by Lloyd Biggle, from 1966
The old fashioned teacher from Mars teaches Shakespeare instead of teaching like this:

He was young, reasonably good-looking, and clever. He balanced chalk on his nose. He juggled erasers. He did imitations. He took up the reading of that modern classic, Saddle Blankets and Six Guns, and he read very well, acting out parts of it, creeping behind his desk to point an imaginary six-gun at the camera.

Other teachers do strip tease acts while discussing grammar:

At precisely two o’clock Marjorie McMillan appeared, and Miss Boltz’s first horrified impression was that she was disrobing. Her shoes and stockings were piled neatly on the floor. She was in the act of unzipping her blouse. She glanced up at the camera.
“What are you cats and toms doing in here?” she cooed. “I thought I was alone.”

Link to story here
